# Schema-form select onChange event

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

I am using Schema-form and i am trying to capture the `onChange` event [like it says here](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/index.md#onchange) in order to save the value selected.

```
vm.form = [{
   key: 'RelationType',
   type: 'select',
   fieldHtmlClass: 'validationStyle',
   onChange: function (modelValue, form) {
       debugger;
       console.log("Value is", modelValue);
  },
   titleMap: JSON.parse(typeList)
}]
```

But i never hit `debugger` in `onChange` function, in  that function, is there another way of doing it?

Comment: Are there any other errors? Which version are you using?